# Delimiters in Java

Tags: java, delimiter

I am trying to figure out how to use delimiters in Java.  Basically, I am trying to parse input like this: "(x1, x2)" into double values.  When I assign variables to the next double, the next integer gets counted as a double instead of the value between delimiters.  How would I separate the values between delimiters and put them into variables?

```
    System.out.print("Enter coordinates for two points as (x1, x2) (y1, y2): ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String wholeString = input.nextLine();
    Scanner stringScanner = new Scanner (wholeString).useDelimiter("[,\\s\\(\\)]*");
    x1 = stringScanner.nextDouble();
    x2 = stringScanner.nextDouble();
    y1 = stringScanner.nextDouble();
    y2 = stringScanner.nextDouble();
    slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you provide some example input and the resulting values of x1 - y2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this delimiter: `[,\\s\\(\\)]+`

`*` means **0** or more